# How to customize user's drill through functionality for consuming SSAS tabular model through excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerbi, ssas-tabular

Need some insights on a peculiar set of requirements for SSAS tabular model (connected through Excel) that I recently came across.

1. I need to block the SSAS Tabular cube ***drill through functionality*** only when connected through Excel (I think this is similar to Excel's pivot table, when once clicks on any cell of a pivot table, all the underlying data is shown in a new table). All other clients (visual studio, PBI etc) shouldn't be impacted if this is something that can be done at all.
2. After that, instead of showing up the underlying data in a new excel sheet, the drill through output needs to be redirected to a Web application or Power BI Report.

Is such a use case supported out of the box ? Or this is something which would need some custom design and implementation (at least for point#2).

Would appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562789/how-to-disable-the-double-click-option-for-drillthrough-action-in-ssas-cube

Comment: Useful, however this link seems to have details on SSAS MDX model only (not sure if such a thing is applicable for Tabular model). And it suggests using RBS (role based security) to achieve this. This probably means the drill-through action would be blocked for all clients (including excel), unless one creates a special role, in the security model, for excel users ?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a solution [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5300/how-to-define-drillthrough-in-analysis-services-tabular-2017/), in principle.

And to prevent users from seeing detail of the underlying table, one can set this property as BLANK().

I need to test it out though.